# $\textrm{Hom}_A(eA, \textrm{rad }eA)=0$?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $K$-algebra and $\textrm{mod} A$ the category of finite dimensitional $A$-modules. Suppose that $e \in A$ is a primitive idempotent. I guess that $\textrm{Hom}_A(eA, \textrm{rad } eA)=0$, where $\textrm{rad } eA$ is the radical of $eA$.

We denote $eA$ by $0 \to \ldots \to 0 \to \overset{K}{e} \to K \to \ldots \to K \ldots$, and  denote $\textrm{rad } eA$ by $0 \to \ldots \to 0 \to \overset{0}{e} \to K \to \ldots \to K \ldots$, where $\overset{K}{e}$ implies that $K$ is located at the position of $e$.  So $\textrm{Hom}_A(eA, \textrm{rad } eA)=0$.

Is my answer right?

Edit: Thank Dustan's Comment, $\textrm{Hom}_A(eA, \textrm{rad } eA)=0$ for a quiver $Q_A$ ($A \cong KQ_A$) with no cycle. If there exist cycles in $Q_A$ ($A \cong KQ_A/I$), $\textrm{Hom}_A(eA, \textrm{rad } eA)$ depends on $I$.

Comment: What if $A = K[x]/(x^2)$ and $e=1$?

Comment: As Dustan's comment exemplifies, this is true iff there are no loops in the ordinary quiver of $A$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein  Thank you. I think $\textrm{Hom}_A(eA, \textrm{rad } eA) \cong K $ for $A = K[x] /(x^2)$, $e=1$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you. By Dustan's commet, I think $1 \overset{\alpha}{\to} 2 \overset{\beta}{\to} 3 \overset{\gamma}{\to} 1$ with relation $(\gamma \beta \alpha)^2 =0$, $\textrm{Hom}_A(eA, \textrm{rad }eA) \neq 0$.